# $geoWithin with $in or $or

Tags: mongodb, geo

I need some help with an issue, the thing is very simple, I've tried this:

```
db.things.find({"position": {'$in': [{"$geoWithin":{"$center": [[10,10],10] } }, null ] } })
```

and this:

```
db.things.find({$or: [{"position":{"$geoWithin":{"$center":[[10,10],10]}}, "position": null}]})
```

Neither of them work, I need all the "things" in that circle or "things" that don't have the position field. I have to add that the query returns only the document that don't have the field, excluding the docs that are in the circle.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$in` will work for you, because as per the documentation

> $in selects the documents where the field value equals any value in the specified array

You can modify the `$or` query as below:

```
db.things.find({"$or": [{"position":{"$geoWithin":{"$center":[[10,10],10]}}, "position":{"$exits": false}}]})
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm getting the same results, only the things without the position fields are returned, is strange.

Comment: What I can make out of your question is, you want the records which fulfill either of the two conditions:

1: They are within the the location that you are searching
OR
2: The ones whose value for `position` field doesn't exist

If this is the requirement, then I think the provided solution must work for you :)

Comment: Your logic is OK, I need the ones that are in the radio of search and the ones that don't have the field, but I only get the last ones. I think that the problem is the $geoWithin operator, because if I test it other fields with the $or and it works fine

Comment: I just read your comment again and I see a diference in the word OR with mine AND, I've tried with $and, and it doesn't work anyway